# How to add a timestamp to google form?

Tags: google-forms, google-form-quiz

Is it possible to add a Timestamp to Google Form? I know that a timestamp information is received to the owner of the form when a submission is made. But I want current time and date information to show on the form. Is it possible? I checked out google apps script, but all the functions I could see are just the options available in the dropdown of google forms UI. I don't want to ask for date as a question, but rather for it to be available on the form like a clock.